# Dudas de composer y Symfony2

Tags: symfony2, composer

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado con Symfony2 que casi sale a producción. Lo inicié con sf 2.8.8 exactamente en su versión standard, y acceso a Internet tengo desde hace muy poco tiempo, por lo que no uso composer (es una locura).
Hasta el momento cada vez que he necesitado algún bundle (de hecho no más de 4) lo descargo manualmente, así como cualquier dependencia que tenga y me rompo el cerebro ubicándolo en los directorios que corresponde y solucionando sus dependencias. En algunos casos cuando son simples me ha servido, pero otras veces he tenido que desistir.
Ahora mismo necesito DoctrineMigrationsBundle; he obtenido el paquete así como la librería migrations, pero no doy con el asunto de dónde va.
Mi duda es si al instalarme composer (y aprender a trabajar con esa maravillosa herramienta) no se fastidia nada de lo que tengo en el proyecto hasta ahora. No valla a ser que mediante composer surja algún error por la declaración de algún namespace de los bundles configurados manualmente.
Repito, los bundles que tengo ahora mismo no son nada complejos e incuso uso extensiones para doctrine sin el bundle.

Comment: Yo hace un tiempo tuve el mismo problema que tu, no uso composer, instalo los bundles a mano y me rompo la cabeza de vez en cuando, pero no había tenido suficiente conexion a internet para buscar o preguntar aqui y lo he dejado un poco de lado porque además, de momento no estoy trabajando con Symfony, pero sí me gustaria saber como usar composer para cuando retome al maravilloso Symfony, ya que ahora tengo mas posibilidades de internet.. me informaré al respecto. Saludos!!

Comment: @AdrianaHernández la forma más simple de tener composer funcionanado es descargando el instalador del propio composer desde https://getcomposer.org/installer, una vez lo tengas desde la consola ejecutas php install (es el archivo descargad), automáticamente se generará un archivo composer.phar que será el que te servirá para instalar paquetes o actualizar dependencias.

Comment: Ok Francisco, muchas gracias, en cuanto tenga un chance lo pongo en práctica!!!

Answer (score 0):

Composer no te debería dar problemas, por el contrario, es una muy buena práctica. Composer se usa para manejar todas las dependencias, sean públicas o repositorios privados. Vale la pena aclarar que como buena práctica no se deben subir las dependencias al sistema de control de versión que uses, solo se debe versionar el archivo composer.json y en algunos casos el archivo composer.lock. Las dependencias se deben instalar en el ambiente local o en los respectivos ambientes de pruebas y producción durante el despliegue.

Comment: la realidad es que ya tengo el sistema versionado (es un GitLab), no se qué mecanismo empleen los administradores para pasar a producción, debo preguntar. Hasta ahora me las he arreglado para construir las dependencias fijándome en el fichero composer de cada bundle, y escribiendo los namespace de acuerdo a la declaración del fichero, si es en el autoload.php de la app o en autoload_psr4, que es lo que debería hacer composer creo. En caso de que logre usar composer, pues probaría quitando los bundles y descargándolos a través de él.